# How to ensure that ckeditor has focus when displayed inside of jquery-ui dialog widget

Tags: ckeditor

I have used `CKEDITOR.appendTo( "my_div" , null , my_string )` to create an instance of ckeditor ... no problem.

however, the LINK button opens a non-interactive LINK dialog box.

So, is there some config setting that it supposed to be manually set to true, perhaps?

---

**EDIT 1** ... I will explain what I meant by *non-interactive LINK dialog box* ...

When I click the ckeditor's LINK button (the one that looks like a chain-link), it opens a LINK dialog box which has a input field for me to enter a URL, plus a pulldown to choose protocol, plus a couple of other form elements.

However, none of these are use-able ... if I try to type in the url input field, nothing happens (the field will not accept focus); likewise the pulldowns do not open if I click them.

---

**EDIT 2** ... added screenshot
[image: ckeditor LINK dialog]

Comment: "a non-interactive" could extend this vague description? Screenshot and your config would also help a lot.

Comment: please see my EDIT-2 ... I added a screenshot

Comment: No good news here, it's really hard to tell exact issue here. But most likely problem is caused by 3rd party application, since correct dialog is displayed.

Comment: it has something to do with focus ... once the LINK dialog is open, if I start typing the text is added directly to the editor itself, instead of into the URL field ... the field never accepts mouse focus and thus the text. ... ... ... (And that directly-added text does not get turned into a link, by the way)

Comment: @Marek ... you seem to be correct ... I was opening the ckeditor within a jquery-ui 'dialog' widget. ... When I open the ckeditor normally, the LINK feature works.

Comment: yup, most likely it might open some transparent overlay with high z-index of sth along these lines. Chromium web inspector/ FF firebug will be your friend now. :)

Comment: found a discussion on this issue: [jquery-ui forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-edit-fields-of-ckeditor-in-jquery-ui-modal-dialog) and also [jquery-ui bugs](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using:

- jquery-1.8.2
- jquery-ui-1.10.3
- ckeditor  4.3.1

then I replaced: *jquery-ui-1.10.3* with: ***[jquery-ui-1.9.0](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/downloads/list)*** and it seems to work as expected.

---

If reverting back to jquery-ui 1.9 is not good for you, also look at:

- [jquery-ui forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-edit-fields-of-ckeditor-in-jquery-ui-modal-dialog) ... "can't edit fields of CKEditor in jQuery UI modal dialog"
- [jquery-ui bugs](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727) ... "Dialog: CKEditor in Modal Dialog is not editable"

Answer (score 2):

When the modal option is set to true for the dialog, the dialog blocks any interaction with elements outside of it. (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/dialog.js#L818)

You can override this to allow interaction with elements inside ckeditor.

Just include this somewhere after jquery ui and it should work:

```
orig_allowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('.cke_dialog').length) {
    return true;
  }
  return orig_allowInteraction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

If you want to allow interaction with any element outside of the dialog, include this instead:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(event) {
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {e.stopImmediatePropagation();});
```