# CKEditor on Modal

Tags: ckeditor

I have a CkEditor 4.x on modal.. I try modal jQueryUI and Bootstrap modal.

When i show Ckeditor in modal and when i use its plugins, fields of plugin don't have a focus, and i can't set it with click. 
[enter link description here](http://prntscr.com/9a5zgk) . 
If i init CkEditor in body, then all OK. But if on modal.then lost focus

I use standart init for CkEditor

```
self.ckwys = CKEDITOR.replace('wysivgBlock', {
   height: 300
});
```

Comment: have you tried `CKEDITOR.instances.ckwys.focus();` ??

Comment: No... Problem only in plugins of ckeditor. Focus set in textarea. And if i open plugin search(for exmpl). field search don't have focus... If i click to search field. focus Remains on a textarea.////

Comment: I cant understand what is the problem. Can you show it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok.. I created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/axfzaht9/
I put ckEditor to popup.. if you open this popup and click to plugins button
http://prntscr.com/9ba5j2
and this fields http://prntscr.com/9ba5ye is not active.!!!

Comment: looks like focus works on firefox but not on Chrome...

Comment: I tested in Firefox, Chrome,Safari ,, and problem remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
modal_this = this
$(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
    if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
    // add whatever conditions you need here:
    &&
    !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
        modal_this.$element.focus()
    }
})
```

};

This code is solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

And this for jqueryUI

```
  var orig_allowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
                $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function (event) {
                    if ($(event.target).closest('.cke_dialog').length) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return orig_allowInteraction.apply(this, arguments);
                };
```

I found solution Here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533487/how-to-ensure-that-ckeditor-has-focus-when-displayed-inside-of-jquery-ui-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Bootstrap modal, you could try to remove `tabindex="-1"` from `modal fade`.
Found this solution [here](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues/263#issuecomment-387546556).